# How to paste one file content in to different files using bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a file with hundreds of names in it, ex:

```
Tokyo
New-York
Rio
Mexico
```

I want to create a empty file using the names of that list and latter apply/paste some text on it coming from another file.

So far I've done `for f in $(cat list_of_names); do paste my text.txt > $f.nnn; done`.

The idea is to generate a filename from the list like `Tokyo.nnn` (and many others) with the contents of `text.txt`

`Tokyo.nnn` will have a text with a configuration coming from `text.txt`. I expect to substitute `$f` with a name from the list while pasting the contents of `text.txt` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create empty file using `xargs touch < list_of_names`.
And if you have a file named text.txt and need the its content in the files being created try this snippet.

```
while read filename; do
       cp -i sample "$filename".nnn
done < list_of_names
```